# polymorphic behaviour through composition in c++ without multilevel inheritance

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism, virtual, composition

I would like to achieve the polymorphic behavior through composition , instead of multilevel inheritance.in below example code bluerectangle is derived from rectangle and bluecircle is derived from circle. so the problem is I might have same depth in inheritance hierarchy so the job is to reduce the hierarchy level using composition instead of multilevel inheritance .can we achieve the polymorphic behavior here with composition, if yes then what design needs to be followed here. currently I just started reading design pattern so it seems to be similar to bridge pattern , but not able to proceed further without having proper pointers.

```
 #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class shape
    {
    public:
    virtual void draw()=0;
    virtual ~shape(){}
    };

    class rectangle: public shape
    {
    public:
    void draw()
    {
    cout<<"draw rectangle"<<endl;
    }
    }; 
    class bluerectangle : public rectangle
    {
    public:
    void draw()
    {
    cout<<"draw bluerectangle"<<endl;
    }
    };
    class circle: public shape
    {
    public:
    void draw()
    {
    cout<<"draw circle"<<endl;
    }

    }; 

    class bluecircle : public circle
    {
    public:
    void draw()
    {
    cout<<"draw bluecircle"<<endl;
    }
    };

    int main()
    {
    shape *obj=new circle;
    obj->draw();
    obj=new rectangle;
    obj->draw();
    obj=new bluerectangle;
    obj->draw();
    obj=new bluecircle;
    obj->draw();
    delete obj;
    return 1;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure where the 'blue' part of you requirements comes from. It sounds like 'Decorator' pattern if you're trying to achieve variability via composition, but it still requires a level if inheritance. It might help if you explain the *why* part of your requirements.

Comment: it is a part of hierarchy  which represent multilevel inheritance .only to represent the class hierarchy it is being  used there.

Comment: inheritance hierarchy seems to be perfect till first level of inheritance till circle and rectangle, but from this point hierarchy seems to be extra overhead if next level inheritance is used, so here from this point job starts to reduce the same by applying composition.

Comment: I still don't understand well. If you give an example of the levels with something concrete, I think it will help.

Comment: Shape->rectangle->bluerectangle or shape->rectangle->redrectangle or any other form of rectangle needs to be refactored in shape->rectangle(colour) . It is a is-a relationship but it can be easily distinguished by colur->red or colur->blue .

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but your code has a memory leak.  You are calling `new` four times and calling `delete` only once.  Learn about smart pointers, in C++11 use std::unique_ptr for this.  I have fixed this in your code in this example on coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8736ed7bea97cd4f

Answer (score 2):

Based on your answers in the comments, this is a classic Decorator pattern.

[image: Decorator applied to OP's problem]

To get a red rectangle, you wrap it:

```
Shape *obj=new RedDecorator(new Rectangle);
obj->draw();
```

The Decorator's `draw()` calls the Rectangle's `draw()` and augments it (decorates it).

Comment: Should that be RedDecorator instead of RedRectangle?

Comment: @amdn indeed. fixing it.

Comment: Thanks for update and updating memory leak issue . I will try to implement this and found any issue then come back to you.